# How to break the 'while' condition when data is not present for the next loop in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Here my Issue is I have a vendor lookup and i have to be read the vendors for search reasult.Here results is
based on search filter (Ex: vendor name begins with,ends with etc.). Here we don't know the count of vendor search results.
I am reding the vendors with while condition with scrolling to next vendor. Here I am unable to break the the while condition 
when all the vendors are fetched. So please let me give the answer for How to write the proper condition to while loop

```
try{
    int i=2;
    boolean ele=d.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='vendorTable']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[1]")).isDisplayed();
    while(ele==true){
        String path="//table[@id='vendorTable']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[1]";    // Here i value starts from 2
        String txt=d.findElement(By.xpath(path)).getAttribute("title");
        System.out.println(txt);
        scrollBarHandle("//table[@id='vendorTable']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[1]");
        i++;
        ele=d.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='vendorTable']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[1]")).isDisplayed()
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Out put Is: 
no such element message is displayed After reading all the vednors.

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[@id='vendorTable']/tbody/tr[9]/td[1]"}

How to break the while loop after all the vendors reading completed.

Comment: The loop has been broken

Comment: Put the try/catch inside the loop.

Comment: Since you have a single iteration for sure, you should consider a `do-while` instead of a `while`, and check if it is `null` or maybe a `try-catch` in addition to checking the value for condition.

Comment: Whether you will be able to get the search result count before doing the scroll action?

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the no of elements that this selector returns and put an if condition on it : 
Below is the code :

```
try{
            int i=2;
            boolean ele=d.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='vendorTable']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[1]")).isDisplayed();
            while(ele==true){
                String path="//table[@id='vendorTable']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[1]";    // Here i value starts from 2
                List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(path));
                if (elements.size() == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                String txt=d.findElement(By.xpath(path)).getAttribute("title");
                System.out.println(txt);
                //scrollBarHandle("//table[@id='vendorTable']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[1]");
                i++;
                ele=d.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='vendorTable']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[1]")).isDisplayed()
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Hope it helps you out.